# How to replace ajax with webrtc data channel

Tags: javascript, ajax, websocket, webrtc, peer

** JAVASCRIPT question **

I'm using regularly ajax via XMLHttpRequest. But in 1 case, I need 1 ajax call per seconds....

but long term wise and with growing number of simultaneous users, it could bloat easily...

I'm reading stuff about webRTC data channel and it seems interesting and promissing.

Here my working AJAX function as an example of how easy and there is a few lines of codes to communicate from the browser to the server and vice-versa

```
function xhrAJAX ( divID , param2 ) {
    // random value for each call to avoid cache
    var pcache = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 100000000) + 1);
    
    // parameters
    var params = "divID="+encodeURIComponent(divID)+"&param2="+encodeURIComponent(param2);
    
    // setup XMLHttpRequest with pcache
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(); 
    xhr.open("POST", "/file.php?pcache="+pcache, true);
    
    // setup headers
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
    // prepare onready scripts
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function(e) { if (xhr.readyState == 4) { $("#"+divID).html(e.currentTarget.responseText) ; } }
    
    // send the ajax call
    xhr.send(params);
}
```

How can I "transpose" or "convert" this ajax **workflow** into a webRTC data channel ? in order to avoid to setup a setInterval 1000...

Note: I mean how to replace the javascript portion of the code. PHP here is only to illustrate, I don't want to do a webRTC via PHP...

Is there a simple few lines of code way to push/receive data like this ajax function ?

the answer I'm looking for is more like a simple function to push and receive
(once the connection with STUN, ICE, TURN is established and working...)

If I need to include a javascript library like jquery or the equivalent for webRTC, I'm welcoming good and simple solution.

*** The main goal is this kind of scenario :
I have a webapp : users in desktop and users within webview in Android and IOS
right now I have this workflow => ajax every 3 seconds to "tell" the main database that the user is still active and using the browser (or the app)

But I'd like to replace with this kind : when the user uses the browser => do a webrtc data chata in background between the browser and the server

While reading on the web I think that webRTC is a better solution than websocket.

** I did a bit of search and found peerjs....
https://github.com/jmcker/Peer-to-Peer-Cue-System/blob/main/send.html

I'll do some testing, but in the meantime, if someone can trow ideas, it could be fun.

Cheers

Comment: Hey Jintor, what language would you like to write you server in? That influences the question a lot. thanks! PHP isn't easily possible unfortunately. Python, Go, C++, node and C# all are really easy.

Comment: @SeanDuBois I was talking about javascript, that's why I pointed out peerjs... the ajax example I put in my question is to show that for ajax it's only a few lines of codes to communicate to the server.